# disable task tag [TODO] jdtls [nvim, cmp, lua]

Tags: lua, neovim, liskov-substitution-principle, cmp

this is my lua config for cmp:

```lua
require('lspconfig')['jdtls'].setup {
    root_dir = function(fname)
        return vim.fn.getcwd()
    end,
    cmd = {
        'jdtls',
        '-vmargs',
        '-Dorg.eclipse.jdt.ls.taskTags=',
        '-Dorg.eclipse.jdt.ls.taskPriorities='
    },
}
```

but still I keep seeing the markers on //TODO

I tried doing lots and lots of configurations, even using "settings" files in the source of my project

Comment: Have you tried adding `settings = { java = { compiler = { taskTags = "", taskPriorities = ""}, }, },` after `cmd = {...}` in the table passed to `setup`, instead of adding the `-Dorg.eclipse.jdt.ls` command options? You might have to pass an empty table instead of empty strings---try both. [This](https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-jdtls#configuration-verbose) configuration example might be of some use as well.